# Пронумеровать id

Tags: javascript, html

На веб-страницах генерируется разное количество блоков div с одинаковым id. 
Блоков

```
<div id="block"></div>
```

на страницах может быть от одного до 5, но не больше. Чтобы получить доступ к каждому блоку нужно их пронумеровать. Например:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="block_1"></div>
    <div id="block_2"></div>
...
```

Как пронумеровать id?

JavaScript это делает. Но, если блоков меньше чем указано, setAttribute пустой.

> Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null(…)

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var el = document.getElementById('block');
        el.setAttribute('id', el.getAttribute('id') + i );  
    }
```

Comment: используйте `class`

Comment: а каким образом потом обращаться к пронумерованным элементам?

Comment: `if (el) { el.setAttribute(...); } else { break; }`

Comment: Grundy `var el = document.getElementById('block_1');`

Comment: Igor `break;` останавливает цикл  после первого блока, ну его.

Comment: @Viher Вы им просто не умеете пользоваться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправить текущий код, можно простым изменением цикла: нужно оставаться в цикле, пока `getElementById` не перестанет находить элементы с указанным id

```js
for (var el = document.getElementById('block'), i = 1; el != null; el = document.getElementById('block'), i++) {
  el.setAttribute('id', el.getAttribute('id') + i);
}
```

```css
div {
  border: solid 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
#block1 {
  border-color: red;
}
#block2 {
  border-color: green;
}
#block3 {
  border-color: blue;
}
#block4 {
  border-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Но лучше не генерировать одинаковые id, а присваивать сразу класс.

Comment: Здорово, спасибо! Еще можно добавить `+ ('_list_') + i` для красоты.

Comment: Почти как мой...

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага :-) я только дольше объяснение писал, и не стал сокращенно вписывать :)

Comment: Хотя непонятно, зачем атрибут вместо свойства. И выборку по id пришлось в двух местах писать.

Comment: _"Сокращённо"_ - это про что вообще?

Comment: @Qwertiy, это про присваивание и получение элемента в блоке проверки :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
for (var i=1, b; b = document.getElementById('block') /* assignment */; ++i) {
  b.id += '-' + i;
}
```

```css
[id]:after { content: attr(id) }
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дать им всем общий класс, к примеру .block

А так-же, каждому дать класс с номером

```
<div class="block block-1"></div>
<div class="block block-2"></div>
<div class="block block-3"></div>
```

Таким образом, вы можете дать общие стили всем им сразу через класс .block, а так же если нужно уникальный стиль для какого то конкретного блока - давать и отдельно ему.

Или Вы хотели динамически давать классы блокам, через скрипт?