# задать id элементам div массива

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть div массив, с неопределённым кол-ом блоков. Необходимо каждому к id добавить +1. Подскажите как сделать что бы id=demo прибавлял к названию номер? demo1, demo2.....

```
    <div class="filter_characteristic">
<a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">1</a>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
<a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">2</a>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
<a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">3</a>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
    </div>
```

РHP код выглядит так:

```
 <div class="filter_characteristic">
    <?php foreach($characteristic_displayfields as $ch_id){?>   
        <?php if (is_array($characteristic_fieldvalues[$ch_id])){?>

    <a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse"><?php print $characteristic_fields[$ch_id]->name;?></a>
       <div id="demo" class="collapse">


            <input type="hidden" name="extra_fields[<?php print $ch_id?>][]" value="0" />            
            <?php foreach($characteristic_fieldvalues[$ch_id] as $val_id=>$val_name){?>
                 <label><span class="button_checkbox"><input type="checkbox" hidden name="extra_fields[<?php print $ch_id?>][]" value="<?php print $val_id;?>" <?php if (is_array($extra_fields_active[$ch_id]) && in_array($val_id, $extra_fields_active[$ch_id])) print "checked";?> onclick="document.jshop_filters.submit();" /> <span><?php print $val_name;?></span></span></label>



            <?php }?>
        <br/></div>
        <?php }?>
    <?php }?>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: У вас html кривой.

Comment: Это выдранный кусок из шаблона.  php код не могу прикрепить к комментарию.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Пронумеровать id](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592262/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-id)

Comment: Хотя, наверное зря закрываю, правильнее тег [tag:php] добавить и давать решение на php...

Comment: Я понимаю, что в начале кода, мне необходимо указать скрипт, который будет изменять id, но все перепробованные мной варианты не работают, т.к. у меня руки кривые. Скрипты из Вашей ссылки пробовал.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">     
for (var el = document.getElementById('demo'), i = 1; el != null; el = document.getElementById('demo'), i++) {
  el.setAttribute('id', el.getAttribute('id') + i);
}
 </script>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не?

```php
 <div class="filter_characteristic">
    <?php foreach($characteristic_displayfields as $ch_id){?>   
        <?php if (is_array($characteristic_fieldvalues[$ch_id])){?>

    <a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse"><?php print $characteristic_fields[$ch_id]->name;?></a>
       <div id="demo<? echo $ch_id ?>" class="collapse">


            <input type="hidden" name="extra_fields[<?php print $ch_id?>][]" value="0" />            
            <?php foreach($characteristic_fieldvalues[$ch_id] as $val_id=>$val_name){?>
                 <label><span class="button_checkbox"><input type="checkbox" hidden name="extra_fields[<?php print $ch_id?>][]" value="<?php print $val_id;?>" <?php if (is_array($extra_fields_active[$ch_id]) && in_array($val_id, $extra_fields_active[$ch_id])) print "checked";?> onclick="document.jshop_filters.submit();" /> <span><?php print $val_name;?></span></span></label>



            <?php }?>
        <br/></div>
        <?php }?>
    <?php }?>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.